# KVM or vSphere for shared access to GPU across virtual machines

Tags: deep-learning, gpu, kvm, vsphere, hypervisor

Aside from opinions about which is liked better and preference for Open Source are there any good reasons to prefer vSphere (the feee version) over KVM when setting up a server for Deep Learning experiments.

The machine is an 8 core Xeon with 64GB RAM and two Nvidia GPS cards.

What I don't know is if GPU virtualization or GPU pass through works better with one hypervisor or the other or even if virtualization is possible with both of them.  If one of the hypervisors allowed two virtual machines to share a GPU that would be a killer feature.

Or is using a hypervisor just a bad idea?  I hope not, but I will listen to reasons.